# RxJava - Single of List<T> to Completable

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have:
`Single<List<T>>`

I want to concurrently run one method on whole list and other method on every element of the list. This two methods returns void, so at last I want to have Completable, which will be completed when all method calls (n+1) will success. All n+1 calls should be run concurrently.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this

You have a `Single<List>` ( I have used `Single<List<Integer>>`)
  say

```
Single<List<Integer>> listSingle = Single.fromCallable(() -> Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
```

1 :  A function which does something with the `Single<List<T>>`

```
public Completable doSomthingWithList(Single<List<Integer>> listSingle) {
    return listSingle.flatMapCompletable(intList -> Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        // do something with intList
        System.out.println("doSomthingWithList");
    })).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); // doing this in a background thread
}
```

2: Another function which does something for all items in the list

```
public Completable doSomethingForEachItemInList(Single<List<Integer>> listSingle) {
    return listSingle.flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable)
            .flatMapCompletable(integer -> Completable.fromAction(() -> {
                System.out.println("Doing somthing with list item " + integer);
            })).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

3: Execute the above 2 functions in parallel , and notifies when both of these have completed

```
 Completable.mergeArray(doSomthingWithList(listSingle), doSomethingForEachItemInList(listSingle))
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    // all actions completed
                    System.out.println("All done!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            });
```